# windows phone, reading level from txt file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0, filereader

I'm working on a windows phone 7 game and I have saved the levels in a text file and i want to load it into a 2D array but there is no content importer for txt files, I have used the isolated storage manager

```
protected void read_lvl()
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {    //Visualize the text data in a TextBlock text

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //for each row
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    //read in the line
                    string myLine = reader.ReadLine();
                    //take out the commas
                    string[] row = myLine.Split(',');

                    //convert to string to ints
                    //and feed back into array
                    int[] nRow = new int[row.Length];
                    for(int r=0; r<columns;r++){
                        nRow[r] =Convert.ToInt32(row[r]);
                        myreadArray[i, r] = nRow[r];
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Which is fine for loading a saved game state etc
But I want to have multiple levels in multiple `.txt` files  and have tried using this instead:

```
        //stream from file
        Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("myFile.txt");
        //make a stream reader from the stream
        using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

But its throwing the same error : There are no importers which handle this file type.

what do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will help you but this is how I load game maps into my game (x and y are my grid coordinates):

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("View.Maps.Breakout_" + _breakoutSelection + ".txt");

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    int y = 0;

    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string data = streamReader.ReadLine();

        int x = 0;

        foreach (var mapSquare in data)
        { code here }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with isolated storage only just by changing the name of file "myfile1.txt" and change the attribute FileMode.OpenOrCreate if you are not having it already.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the file, set the "Build Action" to "None", and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy If Newer" and load it using

```
XDocument.Load(TitleContainer.OpenStream(@"path-to-file.txt"));
```

as shown [here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/50321/303431.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: where will this save it to?
Or do i put it into a var level
Also this is for xml files, how will this work with a .txt 
I want to read it into a 2D array

Comment: Same thing. Building the project will put it inside the XAP in the same directory as in the solution explorer (relative to the root). Do this, rename the XAP to a zip and open it to see where it is.

Comment: Also, note that TitleContainer.OpenStream returns a stream - you can process it using a StreamReader and do whatever you want with the contents.